# How to plot points using hexagonal binning with user defined colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a "scatter plot" of X and Y using hexagonal binning. Currently, I have this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
X=rnorm(1000)
Y=rnorm(1000)
Z=sin(X)
df = data.frame(X,Y,Z)

p = ggplot(df, aes(X, Y)) + 
  stat_binhex()
plot(p)
```

The code produces a plot in which the color of each hexagon represents the number of points in the bin. I want the color to reflect the Z variable in my df (since the points are binned, the color reflect the mean of binned Z). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `stat_summary_hex` and colors can be specified with `scale_fill_continuous`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(X, Y)) +
    stat_summary_hex(aes(z = Z)) +
    scale_fill_continuous(low = 'blue', high = 'red')
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. The only thing I did differently is using scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu") to make the color scale look better